# What is the purpose of define-generic in coops object system in Chicken Scheme

Tags: oop, scheme, chicken-scheme

I'm trying to figure out what is the purpose of define-generic in goops library (http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/coops), it's similar to CLOS if it can help someone (I don't know CLOS either).

I can define a class and a method this way:

```
(define-class <complex> () (x y))

(define-method (sum (a <complex>) (b <complex>))
  (make <complex>
    'x (+ (slot-value a 'x) (slot-value b 'x))
    'y (+ (slot-value a 'y) (slot-value b 'y))))
```

But what is the purpose of this?

```
(define-generic (sum <complex> <complex>))
```

From the docs:

> ```
> [syntax] (define-generic (NAME ARGUMENT ...))
> ```
>
> Defines a generic procedure, a procedure specialized for one or more
>   argument types. ARGUMENT ... defines the number of specialized
>   arguments this generic procedure shoud use to dispatch to the correct
>   method. The generic procedure may receive additional arguments, but
>   those will not be used to determine the method.

Could someone give me a simple example explaining the differences beetween  `define-method` and `define-generic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generic procedure is a special kind of object that consists of (one or) several specialised methods.

`define-generic` defines such an object, and `define-method` adds methods to it, creating it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: This is true. The main use of `define-generic` is if you want to declare that a generic procedure is supposed to exist, but you don't have an implementation for it yet. Basically, you can define a possibly incomplete API with this, much like an abstract base class: `define-generic` ensures the generic procedure exists, so you won't get a "unbound variable" error. The fact that `define-method` works even if you didn't use `define-generic` first to declare it is just for convenience.